# Access a control from within a DataTemplate with its identifying name

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I have a ComboBox control that is located inside a Grid Control. In XAML I am assigning a name to the ComboBox:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name_ru}" Width="Auto" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Name="stcom" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged" Height="auto" Width="Auto">
                 <ComboBox.BorderBrush>
                     <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Color1}"/>
                 </ComboBox.BorderBrush>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

With the method FindName(string) I am trying to refer to the ComboBox with its associated name:

```
ComboBox stcom
        {
            get
            {
                return (ComboBox)FindName("stcom");
            }
        }


 if (stcom != null)
            {
                stcom.ItemsSource = list;
            }
```

But obviously the control can not be found because the reference `stcom` remains null.

The question now is how to refer to my ComboBox using its name property ?

Comment: well `FindName("stcom")` this is not working i think not looking in the controls of the grid.

Comment: if you're using Expander can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422811/accessing-the-children-of-an-expander-control/42381746#42381746

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Grid>
       <TextBlock Name="tbUserIcon" Text="t1" />
       <TextBlock Name="tbCheck"  Text="✓" />
      </Grid>
     </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
 </Style>
```

and C#:

```
checkBox.ApplyTemplate();
var tbUserIcon= (TextBlock)checkBox.Template.FindName("tbUserIcon", checkBox);
```

don't forget the     checkBox.ApplyTemplate() be fore     Template.FindName() it's important!

Answer (score 2):

First you have to get access to the control template which it has been applied to, then you can find an element of the template by name.
Have a look at the MSDN knowledge base :

- [How to: Find ControlTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access controls that are part of a DataTemplate with their name.

You can try to read about some workarounds for example

- [WPF - Find a Control from DataTemplate in WPF](http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.co.at/2010/10/wpf-find-control-from-datatemplate-in.html)

You can also have a look at the dozens of posts here on SO issuing this topic for example

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137967/getting-an-object-reference-by-name-from-a-datatemplate)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162288/access-current-item-in-a-datatemplate)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229514/access-control-within-datatemplate)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380925/programmatically-access-a-control-from-a-datatemplate)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835214/how-to-access-the-label-inside-datatemplate)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450607/access-element-inside-silverlight-datatemplate)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181063/how-to-access-a-specific-item-in-a-listbox-with-datatemplate)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586106/wpf-how-to-access-control-from-datatemplate)

Comment: FYI the first link is being accused by google chrome of containing a malware.